# Free function fails

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am writing a simple program in Linux. Its purpose is to display the GNU version number. But it seems the `free()` function screams at me. When I execute the program. It shows the following:

*** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fa89f028d8a ***

and Backtrace and memory map.

Below is my code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <gnu/libc-version.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
        const char *s;
        s = (const char *)malloc(16*sizeof(char));
        s = gnu_get_libc_version();
        printf("%s\n",s);
        free((char *)s);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is a "GNU version number"? Do Gnus in Africa have versions? And don't cast to/from `void *` in C! `free` takes a `void *`, not a `char *`

Comment: On line 9 you have a memory leak because your memory you allocated is still there but you reassigne it to gnu_get_libc_version(). gnu_get_libc_version returns a constant pointer to string for you. you are trying to FREE memory which does not need to be freed(the gnu_get_libc_version), and calling free on ANYTHING other than dynamic memory pointer causes it to scream at you. hint, the prototype for gnu_get_libc_version is `const char *gnu_get_libc_version(void);` note the const char *, it's often a hint that the string returned is not meant to be freed.

Comment: Thank you ! I realized the question was kinda dumb.

Answer (score 2):

You have lost the pointer returned by `malloc` the moment you reinitialized `s` with the return value of `gnu_get_libc_version`. You are now trying to `free` the pointer returned by `gnu_get_libc_version` which has not been allocated by `malloc`.

You need not `malloc` before calling `gnu_get_libc_version` and do not need to `free` after calling it.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = gnu_get_libc_version();
```

This does not do what you seem to think it does. It looks like you expect it to populate the memory you've allocated previously, memory that is pointed to by `s`.

What it *actually* does is cause `s` to point somewhere totally different, somewhere that is decided by the function `gnu_get_libc_version`.

Given the `free` error and the example usage in the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gnu_get_libc_release.3.html), there's a better-than-even chance this memory is *not* allocated from the heap, hence attempting to free it will cause undefined behaviour.

Assuming that `gnu_get_libc_version` does actually return the address of a C-style string and it's not from the heap (and this certainly appears to be the case base on the link above), you don't need to allocate the memory for it. Instead you can just have:

```
int main(void) {
    const char *s = gnu_get_libc_version();
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

or even the shorter (using `puts` and the return value directly):

```
int main(void) {
    puts(gnu_get_libc_version());
    return 0;
}
```

If you *do* want to get the version information into your own allocated buffer (and assuming you have enough memory for it), you can use:

```
int main(void){
    const char *s = malloc(16);
    strcpy(s, gnu_get_libc_version());
    printf("%s\n", s); // or puts(s)
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This *copies* the string (from the area returned from `gnu_get_libc_version`) into your own buffer, rather than changing `s` to point somewhere else.

---

Notice that I've changed some other things in your original code. The first is to remove the explicit cast of the `malloc` return value. This is something that should not be done in C as it can hide certain subtle errors. C is perfectly capable of *implicitly* casting the `void *` return value to another pointer type.

The second is the cast in `free` which is also unnecessary for the same reason.

The third and final change is to remove the multiplication by `sizeof(char)`. This value is guaranteed by the standard to be `1` so there's no technical reason why it's needed.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very complete and multifaceted. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This function `gnu_get_libc_version()` probably returns a pointer to static memory.

Comment: Even if not, the assignment overwrites the pointer to the allocated memory.

Comment: You're right. This function returns a pointer to static memory.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
s = gnu_get_libc_version();
```

you reassign the `s` to an other `char *` which return by `gnu_get_libc_version`. As the former value of `s`, which was allocated by `malloc`, is lost, which results a memory leak. And the `char *` return by `gnu_get_libc_version` wasn't allocated by `malloc`, so when you call `free` on a pointer which not returned by `malloc`, some error occurs.
s = gnu_get_libc_version();